# Preventing multiple matches in list iteration

Tags: python, numpy

I am relatively new to python, so I will try my best to explain what I am trying to do. I am trying to iterate through two lists of stars (which both contain record arrays), trying to match stars by their coordinates with a tolerance (in this case Ra and Dec, which are both indices within the record arrays). However, there appears to be multiple stars from one list that match the same star in the other. *This is due to both stars matching within the atol. Is there a way to prevent this? Here's what I have so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np    

###importing data###
Astars = list()
for s in ApStars:###this is imported but not shown
    Astars.append(s)

wStars = list()
data1 = np.genfromtxt('6819.txt', dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
for star in data1:
    wStars.append(star)

###beginning matching stars between the Astars and wStars###
list1 = list()
list2 = list()
for star,s in [(star,s) for star in wStars for s in Astars]:
    if np.logical_and(np.isclose(s["RA"],star["RA"], atol=0.000277778)==True , 
                      np.isclose(s["DEC"],star["DEC"],atol=0.000277778)==True): 
        if star not in list1:   
            list1.append(star) #matched wStars
        if s not in list2:
            list2.append(s) #matched Astars
```

I cannot decrease the atol because it goes beyond the instrumental error. What happens is this: There are multiple Wstars that match one Astar. I just want a star for a star, if it is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Off-topic but your `continue` statements don't do anything

Comment: Can you clarify/revise your code? You'r initializing `list1` and `list2` but both of these are empty lists at the time of your `for star, s...` loop.

Comment: Could have been my editing... @Thomas_Grier, could you indent the `continue` statements to their correct location?  (the last `continue` is redundant, but your probably want the first one at the same level as the `if` statements.

Comment: Are you saying you only want to match the first occurrence of each star? I'm confused by your description.

Comment: @Pureferret. That is a really bad suggestion.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've no idea really.  Just trying to be helpful.  Deleting comment in 3...2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all of the you have provided! I did some asking around as well and found a clever way to accomplish what I was searching for. Here is what we came up with:

```
sharedStarsW = list()
sharedStarsA = list()
for s in Astars:
    distance = [((s["RA"] - star["RA"])**2 + (s["DEC"] - star["DEC"])**2)**0.5 for star in wStars]
    if np.amin(distance) < 0.00009259266:
        sharedStarsW.append(wStars[(np.argmin(distance))])
        sharedStarsA.append(s)
```

Using list comprehension, this calculates the distance from an Astar to all wStars and takes all of them that fall within the 1/3 arcsecond. If an Astar star has multiple wStars matches, it appends the Wstar index that gives the shortest distance and its Astar.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your approach entirely to fit the fact that these are astronomical objects you are talking about. I will ignore the loading functionality and assume that you already have your input lists `Astar` and `wStar`.

We will find the *closest* star in `wStar` to each star in `Astar` using a Cartesian dot product. That *should* help resolve any ambiguities about the  best match.

```
# Pre-process the data a little
def getCV(ra, de):
    return np.array([np.cos(aStar['DE']) * np.cos(aStar['RA']),
                     np.cos(aStar['DE']) * np.sin(aStar['RA']),
                     np.sin(aStar['DE'])])

for aStar in Astars:
    aStar['CV'] = getCV(aStar['RA'], aStar['DE'])
for wStar in wStars:
    wStar['CV'] = getCV(wStar['RA'], wStar['DE'])

# Construct lists of matching stars
aList = []
wList = []

# This an extra list of lists of stars that are within tolerance but are
# not best matches. This list will contain empty sublists, but never None
wCandidates []

for aStar in AStars:
    for wStar in wStars:
        # Use native short-circuiting, and don't explicitly test for `True`
        if np.isclose(aStar["RA"], wStar["RA"], atol=0.000277778) and \
           np.isclose(aStar["DEC"], wStar["DEC"], atol=0.000277778):
            newDot = np.dot(aStar['CV'], wStar['CV'])
            if aStar == aList[-1]:
                # This star already has a match, possibly update it
                if newDot > bestDot:
                    bestDot = newDot
                    # Move the previous best match to list of candidates
                    wCandidates[-1].append(wList[-1])
                    wList[-1] = wStar
                else:
                    wCandidates[-1].append(wStar)
             else:
                 # This star does not yet have a match
                 bestDot = newDot
                 aList.append(aStar)
                 wList.append(wStar)
                 wCandidates.append([])
```

The result is that the stars at each index in `wList` represent the best match for the corresponding star in `aList`. Not all stars have a match at all, so not all stars will appear in either of the lists. Note that there may be some (very unlikely) cases where a star in `aList` is not the best match for the one in `wList`.

We find the closest absolute distance between two stars by computing the Cartesian unit vectors based on [these formulas](http://www.astronexus.com/a-a/positions) and taking the dot product. The closer the dot is to one, the closer the stars are together. This should help resolve the ambiguities.

I pre-computed the cartesian vectors for the stars outside the main loop to avoid doing it over and over for `wStars`. The key name `'CV'` stands for Cartesian Vector. Change it as you see fit.

Final note, this method does not check that a star from `wStars` matches with more than one `AStar`. It just ensures that the best `wStar` is selected for each `AStar`.

**UPDATE**

I added a third list to the output, which lists all the `wStars` candidates that were within tolerance of the corresponding `AStars` element, but did not get chosen as the best match.

Comment: I started to implement your solution to my problem, but it turned out to quite complex given the nature of the data table I was working with (meaning I would have to calculate these Cartesian dot products, merge this column to the the data set record array, and go through the rest of the code you provided. Upon inspection by another student, he suggested doing what I have posted below as an answer. I greatly appreciate your help through this process!

Answer (score 0):

First time answering a Question here (if I made a mistake please indicate).But it would seems that what David commented is correct in that "star is always in list1 (and s is always in list2".
So I would suggest comparing and appending to a newlist1/newlist1 that keeps track of star and s.

```
newlist1 = list()
newlist2 = list()

#new list will keep the unique star and s
for star in list1:
    for s in list2:
        #assuming the comparison works haven't test it yet
        if np.logical_and(np.isclose(s["RA"],star["RA"], atol=0.000277778)==True , np.isclose(s["DEC"],star["DEC"],atol=0.000277778)==True):
                if star not in newlist1:
                    newlist1.append(s)
                if s not in newlist2:
                    newlist2.append(s)
                break
                #once a match is found leave the second loop
```

Comment: I don't believe this would work for what I am doing, because each data set has unique data, and I will ultimately combine them in the end (which is why I need even numbers of stars). Appending 's' to both list will only tell me which stars got matched and which didn't.

Comment: Ah, apologies I misinterpreted what you wanted as a result. I will try to be more careful in future answers on this site.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully absorbed your issues, but I'll start with trying to simplify your calculation.

Looks like `Apstars` and `data1` are structured arrays, both 1d with the same `dtype`.

This list iteration could be replaced with:

```
Astars = list()
for s in ApStars:###this is imported but not shown
    Astars.append(s)
```

with

```
Astarrs = list(ApStars)
```

or just omitted.  If you can iterate on `ApStars` here, you can iterate on them in the list comprehension.  Same for `wStars`.

I'd rewrite the comparison as:

```
set1, set2 = set(), set()   
# for star,s in [(star,s) for star in data1 for s in ApStars]:
# iteration on this list comprehension works, 
# but I think this nest iteration is clearer
for star in data1:
    for s in ApStars:
         x1 = np.isclose(s["RA"],star["RA"], atol=0.000277778)
         x2 = np.isclose(s["DEC"],star["DEC"],atol=0.000277778)
         # isclose returns boolean, don't need the ==True
         if x1 & x2:
             set1.add(star)
             set2.add(s)
```

Adding without replacement is easy with `set`, though the order is not defined (same as with dict).

I'd like to explore whether 'extracting' the relevant fields before iteration is would help.

```
Apstars['RA'], data1['RA'], Apstars['DEC'], data1['DEC']

x1 = np.isclose(Apstars['RA'][:,None], data1['RA'], atol=...)
x2 = np.isclose(Apstars['DEC']....)

x12 = x1 & x2
```

`x12` is a 2d boolean array; `x12[i,j]` is True when `Apstars[i]` is 'close' to `data1[j]`.